# How to format json date in javascript

Tags: json, grails

I am using `grails`.
After render object as json, here what i got :

```
result : {"temp {"class":"com.mine.domain.Guest","id":32,"address":"","city":"",
"country":null,"customerType": {"class":"CustomerType","id":1},
**"dob":"1984-07-10T16:00:00Z"**.......
```

How to reformat dob to `dd/mm/yyyy` in jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not JSON. How is this produced in grails?

Comment: def result = ["temp" : guest,'nationality' : guest.nationality,'country' : guest.country] as JSON;
render result;

Comment: In JavaScript did you try `new Date(dob)`? You could then format that any way you want

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery dateTimePicker will do the job http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
var datestringToDate = function(datestring){
    var myDate = datestring.substr(0,10).split("-");
    return myDate[2] + '/' + myDate[1] + '/' + myDate[0];
}
```

datestringToDate("1984-07-10T16:00:00Z"); will return "10/07/1984"

If you decide to use this, you also got to make sure that the dates come in always in the same format ("YYYY-MM-DDTGIBBERISH"), since it's just a simple string parser and nothing else.